# Find an atlas of $\mathbb R$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Find the atlas of $1$-dimentional Euclidian space $\mathbb R$.

---

For each $a\in \mathbb R$, define $U_a:=(a-1, a+1)$ and $\varphi_a : U_a \to (a-1,a+1)$ by $\varphi_a(y)=y$.

Then, each $\varphi_a$ is homeomorphism from open set in $\mathbb R$ to open set in $\mathbb R$, and I have $\displaystyle\bigcup_{a\in \mathbb R}\ U_a=\mathbb R.$

Thus, $\{(U_a, \varphi_a)\}_{a\in \mathbb R}\ $  is atlas of $\mathbb R$.

---

Is this O.K. ?

Comment: You have not shown that the transition maps are smooth. This is indeed an atlas, but it’s pretty overkill. What’s wrong with the global chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oiler said in his comment, this is correct. But in an atlas you don't need to have a separate chart for each point. But there must be a chart for each point that covers that point, but it can be one chart that works for all points. So, more easily $\{(\mathbb{R}, \textrm{id})\}$, where $\textrm{id}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the identity map $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: This atlas does indeed cover all of $\mathbb{R}$. With how they have been defined:  $a \in U_{a} : = (a - 1 , a + 1)$ for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$.